# libgpiod recipe requires a kernel header: linux/gpio.h

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, gpio, bitbake, openembedded

I'm trying to pull this libgpiod library using Yocto/OpenEmbedded and build it under my recipes-support:
https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/139782/

While I bitake the recipe, it complaints about a missing 'kernel' header:

```
configure: error: linux/gpio.h header not found (needed to build the library)
```

How do I put information about this header in the recipe? Is there or should there be a patch? From whatever I could read, seems libgpiod is user space application/tools. Why would it try to get kernel header?

I'm using 4.19.0+ kernel and Angstrom distro. Thanks.

Comment: Kernel header provides an interface which user space app can use. Or how do you think applications know how to speak to kernel?

Comment: Understand that. But my question is: how to convey that info to downloaded recipe? Is it controlled by some bitbake variable?
I got bunch of other recipes from recipes-support but never had to customize them. That is the idea behind these 'support' recipes, i believe.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Poky and Yocto Thud, Warrior and Zeus. Adding libgpiod to our image (https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/zeus/recipes/?q=libgpiod) pulls in whatever build dependency is needed, builds libgpiod libraries and tools, installs libraries and tools to the target image and libraries and headers to the sdk.

Which Yocto are you using? And how do you pull the libgpiod library?

We use: IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libgpiod" which takes the recipe from 'poky'.

Comment: Thanks Ferry for the reply. I'm pretty new to all this Yocto thing. We're using Yocto but not sure which one. Can you please tell how/where I can find that info (Thud, Warrior, or Zeus)?
I just put .inc and .bb files under /recipes-support in our recipes repository and our build process picks/downloads the code.

Comment: Sure, we are here https://github.com/edison-fw/meta-intel-edison. We are using a make file that calls a setup script that downloads poky. But general docs are here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/.

I'm not sure if that applies to you as you are using Angstrom - which i believed to be a binary distro?

Comment: What worked for me is adding `libgpiod-tools` as well. The complete line would be:
`IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libgpiod libgpiod-tools "`. Otherwise, if only specified `libgpiod`, only the shared libraries would be installed, and no command line tools.

Comment: I think you are copying individual recipes into your own layer? That is not the preferred method. The idea is to download/checkout the complete layer(s) as our setup script does, then any dependencies can be automatically resolved.
In your own layer you would only add your own recipes (or appends to existing one).